# Duplicate MYSQL Record with child records

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the code below to duplicate a event record in my database, problem is I am trying to also duplicate any child records (i.e. event services). I need it to copy all "event services" from the eventservices table as well as update the eventid during copy to the newly copied id record. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Note: The eventservices table has a eventid field which matches the id of the event.

```
$table = 'events';
$id_field = 'id';
$id = $_GET['eventid'];
DuplicateMySQLRecord($table, $id_field, $id);



function DuplicateMySQLRecord($table, $id_field, $id) {

        include_once 'db_connect.php';
      // load the original record into an array
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE {$id_field}={$id}");
      $original_record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

      // insert the new record and get the new auto_increment id
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO {$table} (`{$id_field}`) VALUES (NULL)");
      $newid = mysql_insert_id();

      // generate the query to update the new record with the previous values
      $query = "UPDATE {$table} SET ";
      foreach ($original_record as $key => $value) {
        if ($key != $id_field) {
            $query .= '`'.$key.'` = "'.str_replace('"','\"',$value).'", ';
        }
      }
      $query = substr($query,0,strlen($query)-2); # lop off the extra trailing comma
      $query .= " WHERE {$id_field}={$newid}";
      mysql_query($query);

      // return the new id
      return $newid;

    }
```

Comment: Let me know how are you managing the child events?like are you using any parent id ?

Comment: Yes the child events have a column eventid and it stores the id for the event

Comment: First of all don't do insert than update(2 mysql queries). Prepare your new event than do insert(1 mysql query). More efficient!

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code.I have not compile this code so test before use.

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
$table = 'events';
$id_field = 'id';
$id = $_GET['eventid'];
DuplicateMySQLRecord($table, $id_field, $id);
function DuplicateMySQLRecord($table, $id_field, $id) {

  // load the original record into an array
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE {$id_field}={$id}");
  $original_record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

  // insert the new record and get the new auto_increment id
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO {$table} (`{$id_field}`) VALUES (NULL)");
  $newid = mysql_insert_id();

  // generate the query to update the new record with the previous values
  $query = "UPDATE {$table} SET ";
  foreach ($original_record as $key => $value) {
    if ($key != $id_field) {
        $query .= '`'.$key.'` = "'.str_replace('"','\"',$value).'", ';
    }
  }
  $query = substr($query,0,strlen($query)-2); # lop off the extra trailing comma
  $query .= " WHERE {$id_field}={$newid}";
  mysql_query($query);

  if($newid) {
    $oldid = $id;
    copychilds($table, 'eventid', $oldid,$newid);
  } 
  // return the new id
  return $newid;

}

function copychilds($table, $id_field, $oldid,$newcopiedid) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE id={$oldid}");
    while($original_child_record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result){
        // insert the new record and get the new auto_increment id
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO {$table} (`id`) VALUES (NULL)");
        $newid = mysql_insert_id();

        // generate the query to update the new record with the previous values
        $query = "UPDATE {$table} SET ";
        foreach ($original_record as $key => $value) {
            if ($key != 'id') {
                $query .= '`'.$key.'` = "'.str_replace('"','\"',$value).'", ';
            }
        }
        $query .= '`'.$id_field.'` = "'.str_replace('"','\"',$newcopiedid).'", ';
        $query = substr($query,0,strlen($query)-2); # lop off the extra trailing comma
        $query .= " WHERE id={$newid}";
        mysql_query($query);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have all of this working with a few tweaks.

Below is my function, everything is working great, however, it only gets the first record and there may be multiple children. Any help appreciated.

```
function copychilds1($table, $id_field, $oldid,$newcopiedid, $updatedid) {
    include_once '../inc/db_connect.php';

  // load the original record into an array
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE {$id_field}={$oldid}");
  $original_record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

  // insert the new record and get the new auto_increment id
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO {$table} (`{$id_field}`) VALUES (NULL)");
  $newid = mysql_insert_id();
  // generate the query to update the new record with the previous values
  $query = "UPDATE {$table} SET ";
  foreach ($original_record as $key => $value) {
    if ($key != 'id') {
        $query .= '`'.$key.'` = "'.str_replace('"','\"',$value).'", ';
    }
  }
  $query = substr($query,0,strlen($query)-2); # lop off the extra trailing comma
  $query .= " WHERE id={$newid}";
  mysql_query($query);
  $finalquery = "UPDATE eventservices SET eventid = {$updatedid} WHERE id = {$newid}";
  mysql_query($finalquery);

  // return the new id
  return $newid;
}
```